# Exception in installing yii2

Tags: composer-php, yii2

When i tried to install `Yii2` using composer

I had this exception

```
Script yii\composer\Installer::postCreateProject handling the post-create-project-cmd event terminated with an exception

  [Exception]                                    
  The mcrypt PHP extension is required by Yii2.
```

how can i solve this ?

Comment: I get that error message even mcrypt was already installed on my machine. I just ignore it and project works fine...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to install mycrypt first to the php.

See the link below:
http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.installation.php

Comment: Run php5enmod mcrypt; 
service apache2 restart